# JAVA cmd (JDK) not starting even after re-installing jdk

Tags: java, installation

Java is not starting up in command prompt. The command prompt, when clicked is displayed on the screen for less than a second and disappears again. Following this, i have removed and re-installed jdk again and set the environment variables. But the problem persists. Can anyone help me on this, i tried searching for this kinda problem but not able to find a solution.

On a side note, recently i have installed 'webroot' antivirus and i've noticed that it stopped mysql also, which i was able to start by using services.msc . I tried the same, but java doesn't show up in services.msc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this would help solving your problem:

http://en.kioskea.net/faq/7321-windows-7-keeping-a-command-prompt-window-opened